# PHP for loop to while loop

Tags: php

Hey studying for exams and have this loop.

```
<?php 
$ab = 0; 
$xy = 1; 

echo "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {     
    echo "<tr>";     

    echo "<td>" . $ab . "</td><td>" . $xy . "</td>";
    $ab += $xy;     $xy += $ab;     

    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
```

the question is now how do i rewrite this as while loop ? what to keep in mind,

thanks !

Comment: Well have you even tried something and got stuck somewhere or are you just asking us to code for you?

Comment: `while ($i < 5)` ... then increment `$i` in the `while`, no? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: Sure this is a good strategy to actually _learn_ something? By asking for the answer of a question?

Comment: @arkascha I asked what to keep in mind .. and I do learn by seeing how the code is then I can figure out how it works. Didnt say I was good or anything

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the way one learns to code. You will be much more successful if you instead take the definitions of the loop constructs (see the official documentation with examples) and figure things out yourself. When having done that, you can say that you understood how to use those language constructs.

Comment: Your question asks what should you keep in mind? Personally, I'd keep in mind "does it make sense to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?" Because in the example you gave, it absolutely, 100% does NOT make sense to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ab = 0; 
$xy = 1;
echo "<table>";
$i = 0;
while ($i < 5) {
    echo "<tr><td>$ab</td><td>$xy</td></tr>";
    $ab += $xy;
    $xy += $ab;
    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

For explanation :
Compared to the "for" loop, you have to initialize the "counter" before opening the loop [ $i = 0 ]
Inside the loop, you specify the condition to continue the loop [ $i < 5 ]
And somewhere into the loop, you increase your "counter" [ $i++ ]
Your "counter" can be increased or decreased, or directly set ; it's all about your code logic and what are your needs.

You can also break the loop whenever you want in case you need to, see an example :

```
while ($i < 5) {
    echo "<tr><td>$ab</td><td>$xy</td></tr>";
    $ab += $xy;
    $xy += $ab;
    if ($ab == 22) { // If $ab is equal to a specific value
        /* Do more stuff here if you want to */
        break; // stop the loop here
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This example also work with the "for" loop.
And there is also another keyword, "continue", used to tell to "jump" to the next loop iteration :

```
while ($i < 5) {
    $i++; // Don't forget to increase "counter" first, to avoid infinite loop
    if ($ab == 22) { // If $ab is equal to a specific value
        /* Do more stuff here if you want to */
        continue; // ignore this iteration
    }

    /* The following will be ignored if $ab is equal to 22 */
    echo "<tr><td>$ab</td><td>$xy</td></tr>";
    $ab += $xy;
    $xy += $ab;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

To replace a `for` loop with a `while` loop, you can declare a variable before you initiate the while loop which will indicate the current iteration of the loop. Then you can decrement/increment this variable upon each iteration of the while loop. So you would have something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < 5) {
  echo "";
  echo "<td>" . $ab . "</td><td>" . $xy . "</td>";
  $ab += $xy;     
  $xy += $ab;     
  echo "</tr>"; 
  $counter++;
}
```

in general:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < x; $i++) {
  do stuff
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < x){
  do stuff
  counter++;
}
```